# Webpack: vendor bundle not imported in main output

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I'm struggling with what looks like a generic error from Webpack after trying to optimise my source code.

Assuming I have the following files in `./src:`

> ```
> ├── main.js
> ├── moduleA.js
> └── moduleB.js
> ```

```
main.js imports and uses ModuleA.

moduleA.js imports and uses ModuleB

ModuleA.js and ModuleB.js both import flatten-array from node_modules
```

**My expectation is that if I try to optimise my bundle (see below) it will output two files:**

```
1. index.js
2. vendors~main.index.js
```

**Trying to execute the `index.js` output bundle results in:**

```
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module,
module.exports, __webpack_require__);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

**Although the files are generated, `index.js` doesn't appear to import vendors~main.index.js. Yet it executes fine when removing the optimization (and vendors javascript)**

**Is this the correct assumption? How can I make it work like this?**

While this is a bundle for Node, there are valid reasons that I'd like to export a vendors file.

Accompanying git repo to reproduce available here:

https://github.com/supasympa/webpack-vendors-issue

Files are:

#### main.js

```
const  moduleA  = require('./moduleA');

moduleA.log('log from main.js');
```

---

### moduleA.js

```
const moduleB = require('./moduleB');
const flatten = require('array-flatten');

module.exports.log = function(msg){
    moduleB.log('logging from moduleA.js');
    console.log(`ModuleA logging: ${msg}`);
    console.log(`flattened: ${flatten([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7]])}`)
};
```

---

### moduleB.js

```
const flatten = require('array-flatten');

module.exports.log = function(msg){
    console.log(`ModuleB logging: ${msg}`);
    console.log(`flattened: ${flatten([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7]])}`)
};
```

---

### webpack.config.js

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
        module: {
            rules: [{
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
                loader: 'babel-loader',

                options: {
                    plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import'],

                    presets: [['env', {
                        'modules': 'commonjs'
                    }]]
                },

                test: /\.js$/
            }]
        },

        entry: './src/main',
        target: 'node',

        output: {
            filename: 'index.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },

        mode: 'development',

        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendors: {
                        priority: -10,
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        enforce: true
                    },
                },
                // concatenateModules: false,
                chunks: 'all',
                minChunks: 1,
                minSize: 0,
                name: true
            }
        },

        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is not yet implemented outside of the browser, in Webpack.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8330

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8161

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8156

Answer (score 0):

Defining, `chunks: 'all',` you're explicitly taking all initial entries and async imports (by default it only  on-demand async chunks) and specifying the bundler to create a new vendor chunk/file out of that.

So the behavior is as expected. The idea is to remove the common dependencies from entry files so they can be shared and the page has to load less vendors/common code overall.

One way to explicitly control what the entry files include is this pattern: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/two-explicit-vendor-chunks

Comment: thanks for the response. Could you elaborate further? In the example, the output index.js is not expected to import the vendor.js? Then it’s not expected to execute? This is confusing at best.